# iOS app closes/crashing after splash screen only in Debug configuration mode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

My app works absolutely perfectly on the simulator and when it is distributed as a Release configuration via my CI - all good. However, if I distributed it in Debug configuration (everything else remains the same) it always automatically closes or crashes straight after splash screen.

I was trying to export it as a `development` and `development provisioning profile` and `adhoc` and `adHoc provisioning profile` same result.

I have been battling with this issue for a few days now, please advise where to start and how to identify where the problem is.

I am running `XCode 11.5` and the app has been developed using `react-native`. I am using `crashalytics` to capture the crash reports but for some reason, there is nothing in there.

Comment: Have you looked at any crash logs?

Comment: @andlin I am using `crashalytics` to capture the crash reports but for some reason, there is nothing in there.

Comment: Have you uploaded the dSYM files to Crashlytics/Firebase?

Comment: @andlin I am using firebase distribution to upload artifact, does it uploads it automatically or dSYM needs to be uploaded separately anyway?